# Wordpress RSS feed only download or err 403

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, rss, wget

i have WordPress installed on my server but if i try to open the rss feed it will download only the xml file without the .xml extension! The log files of my server:

```
x.x.x.x - - [04/Dec/2018:21:18:39 +0100] "GET /wordpress/index.php/feed/rss/ HTTP/1.1" 301 3871 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0"
x.x.x.x - - [04/Dec/2018:21:18:40 +0100] "GET /wordpress/index.php/feed/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6463 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0"
```

if i try to open the rss feed with wget it come's following error:

```
2018-12-04 21:31:30 FEHLER 403: Forbidden.
```

Sys info:

```
Debian 9
Apache2
WordPress 4.9.8
php 7.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the Problem: **CloudFlare**! I must turn off *Browser integrity check*